# What are the ways to make custom text field non searchable in salesforce global search?

Tags: global-search

I want to make a custom field (Text) non searchable in global search. Please advice.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is to make it an encrypted text field. That makes it unsearchable. But then you make the data inaccessible to all but those with "view encrypted text" permissions.

Comment: You can make use of formula type where this type can't be searchable...

Answer (score 6):

Fields searched in the global search depends upon the field level security on Profile.
if Profile does not have access to particular field then that field will not appear in the global search.